# compare string key with object and return value

Tags: javascript

I have this function to check and return the value if key is equal to object key.

for example key is code and object have {'code':'123', 'name':'mokee'}, so in this case function should return  123. But below code condition is working but return always null.

```
 hasSameProps( prop, obj ) {
        let keys = Object.keys( obj )
         keys.forEach(function(key){
          if(key===prop){
            return obj[key];
          }
         });
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: You can use `obj[prop]` to have "prop" evaluated and the result used as a key.

Comment: rather than looping though all props you could do `return typeof obj[prop] !== 'undefined' ? obj[prop] : null`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but doesn't `obj[prop]` achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone your pieve of code will fail for falsey values, like `0`, `""`, `NaN` etc. Rather than using `||` you should use `??`

Comment: this is not working